# PHP Class to store CSS variables

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm trying to store CSS variables in a MySQL table. Because the variable and keys change every time, I created a PHP class to keep things in model. Is this a good way of doing this?

```
public function pushCSSVariable($key, $variable)
{
    $keyInput = (string) $key;
    $this->_cssData[$keyInput][] = (string) $variable;
}
public function getCSSVariablesByKey($key)
{
    $keyInput = (string) $key;
    if (!isset($this->_cssData[$keyInput]))
    {
        return $this->_cssData[$keyInput];
    }
    return FALSE;
}
public function getCSSData()
{
    return $this->_cssData;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. And from the little I do understand, what you're doing is basically a glorified array. So use an array...

Comment: The problem is that users can add there own css to a part of the website. This class is then added to the class of the output component and stored serialized in the database.

Comment: Sounds like a bad plan. Why are you letting users write CSS rules?

Comment: It's generated from a form. And it's there website so why not let them change a few small things. We have more then +50000 users, can do this for them..